# Chain of $m+1$ of anti-chain of $n+1$

Tags: combinatorics

Theorem: Given any poset of $mn+1$ elements, prove that there exists either a chain of length $m+1$ or an anti-chain of length $n+1$.

I proved this with an ugly proof. Is there any proof using theorems about poset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your poset $P$. For each $x\in P$ let $f(x)$ be the length of the longest chain having $x$ as its greatest element. Note that $x\lt y\Rightarrow f(x)\lt f(y)$; hence, for each $k\in\mathbb N$, the set $A_k=\{x\in P:f(x)=k\}$ is an antichain.

If $f(x)\ge m+1$ for some $x\in P$, there is a chain of length $m+1$. Otherwise, $P$ is the union of the $m$ antichains $A_1,\dots,A_m$. Since $|P|=mn+1$, one of those antichains must contain at least $n+1$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

Let  $P$ be the set of $mn+1$ elements with partial order.Suppose that there isn't a chain in $P$  with at least $m+1$ elements. Then $height(P)\leq m$. Then $a(P)\leq m$ which means that $P$ can be broken in $m$ at most  anti-chains $A_{i}$. From hypothesis of #$P\geq mn+1$ we have that #$A_{i}\geq n+1$ for one at least anti-chain $A_{i}$.

$height(P)$ is the number of elements of the maximum chain in $P$.

$a(P)$ is the minimum number of anti-chains in $P$.

Comment: Looks like you created a duplicate account to up-vote your answers. Reaching a reputation of 200 within 10 minutes :-). These up-votes will be undone by the script :-)

Comment: @user17762, yes.i made a mistake.can you remove them plz?

Comment: No worries. It will get reversed within a day. There is a script which automatically detects suspicious voting. I am +1 ing this answer, since you were bold enough to accept. Pat your self on your back. True courage is when you accept and men of courage are hard to see.